# Cancelling a test run in SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I currently have a test step which calls another test case. In the called test case, I have a groovy script with a conditional if statement. If a certain condition is met I want to cancel the current execution. I've added the below two lines;

testRunner.cancel("Condition not met");
return

What I find however, is that control is passed back to the test case in which the call was made from, and it continues to execute the remaining test steps within the case. The only way around this is to use testRunner.fail(""), but this is not really what I want.

Please can anyone advise. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing **testRunner.cancel** in the called step. You can return 0/1 from the called **groovy** step

```
return 0
```

Based on the value received in calling function 0 or 1 , you can do

```
testRunner.cancel("Cancelling the test run further steps as there is a failure")
return
```

Comment: This would do it. But remember the "return", or else the current script in the target testcase will run all the way to the end. From the phrasing of the question, I assume the OP is doing a testCase.run(), and thus won't get the 1 or 0 returned directly, but will need to go to the specific teststep to retrieve it afterwards... If there are more than one groovy script teststep in a testcase that may abort, you will need to traverse the teststeps to see if any of them returned 0...?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing your script run() on the testcase, you may catch the result of that testcase, and then choose how to act.

```
def result = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getTestCaseByName("The Name Of Your Testcase").run(null, false);
def status = result.getStatus()
if (status == com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner.Status.CANCELED) {
    testRunner.cancel("Condition not met"); 
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, these are both great options,  however I am calling the test case via the 'Run Test Case' option. I need to do it this way (rather than using a groovy script) to keep it thread safe as I need to select the option 'Run Primary TestCase (wait for running to finish, Thread-Safe').